# how to make sql group by week total

Tags: sql-server

sql server group by week sum

I have below code, time table.
below are time table columns

below is user table columns
userid,firstname,lastname

below are records of time table

```
timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid
1,1st Jun 2019,1:00,10:00,1
2,2st Jun 2019,1:00,10:00,2
3,3rd Jun 2019,4:00,11:00,1
10,11th Jun 2019,4:00,11:00,1
14,11th Jun 2019,4:00,11:00,1
19,11th Jun 2019,4:00,11:00,1
```

my question is I want to generate weekly total report
like below e.g.

```
Userid | 3rd June to 9th June | 10th to 16 June
1              10                     20
2               5                      5
```

I have tried below code

```
 select sum(datediff(hour,startdate,enddate),userid,shiftdate from time 
group by userid,shiftdate
```

my it is giving me total of daily with respect to user. but what i need
I ned to have sum of hours between first day of week to last day of each week.

my it is giving me total of daily with respect to user. but what i need
I ned to have sum of hours between first day of week to last day of each week.
can you help on it

Comment: You wants weeks in column? How many weeks will be there?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
DECLARE @TimeTable TABLE(
timeid INT,shiftdate DATETIME ,starttime TIME,endtime TIME ,userid INT
)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(1,'1 Jun 2019','1:00','10:00',1)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(2,'2 Jun 2019','1:00','10:00',2)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(2,'3 Jun 2019','1:00','10:00',2)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(3,'3 Jun 2019','4:00','11:00',1)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(10,'11 Jun 2019','4:00','11:00',1)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(14,'11 Jun 2019','4:00','11:00',3)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(19,'11 Jun 2019','4:00','11:00',3)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(2,'11 Jun 2019','1:00','10:00',2)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(10,'19 Jun 2019','4:00','11:00',1)
INSERT INTO @TimeTable(timeid,shiftdate,starttime,endtime,userid) VALUES(10,'20 Jun 2019','4:00','11:00',1)

;WITH WeeklyTotal
AS(
SELECT * 
      ,DATEDIFF(HOUR,starttime,endtime) totalHours
      ,DATEPART(WEEK, shiftdate) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,shiftdate), 0))+ 1  AS weekOfMonth
FROM @TimeTable
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT userid,weekOfMonth,totalHours
FROM WeeklyTotal
) aaa
pivot
(
  SUM(totalHours)
  for weekOfMonth in ([1], [2], [3],[4],[5],[6])
) piv;
```